# Why is FIFO not guaranteed for Azure Service Bus queues?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I saw that session is used to ensure FIFO processing for azure service bus queues. But i would like to understand why is FIFO not supported on default (without using session key). Is it due to concurrent consumer of 1 single queue?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe it is explained here very nicely: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions#first-in-first-out-fifo-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, messages will be received in a FIFO manner even without sessions, but there isn't a guarantee in this case. Only having a single subscriber able to fully lock it's partition is the key here.

This may make more sense with an example of how things can be received out of order without sessions. Let's say we have two receivers A and B starting with 2 messages in queue.

1. A picks up the first message.
2. B picks up the second message.
3. A third message is added to the queue.
4. A fails to process the message correctly and the first message is returned to the queue. It goes to the back of the line, and will be next delivered *after* the third message.
5. After recovering, A picks up the third message.
6. B completes the second message. It picks up the next item in the queue, which was actually the first message sent. These two messages are now out of order.

With sessions, each message will be given to either A or B exclusively, and the order of the messages is maintained.

Comment: Thank you Samara. For point 4, Is your situation using peek-lock or receive-and-delete? Because I thought, if A failed to process the message correctly, it doesnt goes to the back of the line, but stays as <1st message, 3rd message>?

Comment: Receive and delete would remove it from the queue regardless of whether the process succeeds or fails. When a message is returned to the queue due to a lock expiring or being explicitly returned it is treated by Service Bus as a new message, thus ending up at the back of the line and out of order. Using receive-delete you *probably* won't lose FIFO, but it's still not a guarantee.

With partitions, messages are handled in order explicitly- aka until the first message completes in a given partition, the second is not available, thus it is able to guarantee FIFO.

Comment: I see! I am wondering if you could provide any link with regards to the part that service bus will treat expired messages as new messages (hence placed at the end of the line)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I may need to go back a little bit on the example (I remember it working that way but it's been awhile since I tested it.) It mentions in this article that it will pick it back up immediately after the lock expires: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#additional-information. The concept still applies though. You could have any number of messages process while waiting for that lock to expire.

Comment: I see, meaning it could probably process other message while the failed message lock has not expired, when the application is back up right? Do you mind if you could update the answer above on this and I will accept the answer thereafter. Thank you!